# How to fetch "last login/accessed" time of Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I want to get a list of Azure virtual machines that were not accessed / logged in for a week, so I can send an email to the users if these can be de-provisioned.

I used the below cmdlet to check the last accessed/login details, but it doesnot give me those details.

```
$vm = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName "ADL-RG" -Name "W1905" -Status
```

Can anyone help me with the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the last login information about users through the PowerShell command. All the VM information you can get shows in the [Azure VM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2019-03-01/virtualmachines). As I know, you can try to execute the command inside the VM to get the login information in the logs when you remote login the VM. Or execute the command through the PowerShell command [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-2.1.0). For example, the login information in Ubuntu is stored in the log /var/log/auth.log. So you can get the info from the file.

Comment: I'd suggest you treat rest api as the source of truth, not the template reference

Comment: @4c74356b41 I think the output of the REST API is the same as the template, is it?

Comment: if you run it - yet, if you are reading arm template docs - it might be behind. in general it makes no sense anyway to quote arm templates, when you can quote the source

Comment: @4c74356b41 OK, that's great advice. I will take care of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see these details using the sign in section in Azure Active Directory portal
[image]

You can use powershell to access activity logs e.g:
Get-AzLog -StartTime 'put start time here' -EndTime 'put end time here'

Other option is to use the REST API
There is a $filter query parameter which you can use for filtering the results.This call returns a list of  signIn objects in the response.
You need to have permission to make this call for which you need access token

Comment: pretty sure this is referring to something else, logins wouldn't be visible in the activity log or in the rest api

Comment: That is correct.  Activity Log only logs management plane operations going through Azure Resource Manager (ARM), not VM logins